# ASP.NET Core: get section of appsettings.json as immutable record

Tags: asp.net, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

Is there a clean way to read in a section of `appsettings.json` as an immutable record?

For example, if my `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "MySection": {
    "Id": 5,
    "Names": { "John": "Manager", "Sally": "Boss" }
  }
}
```

What's the best way to turn this into an object of the following class:

```cs
public record MyConfig(int Id, ImmutableDictionary<string, string> Names);
```

Just doing the following doesn't work since it results in the error below (I understand the error, but am looking for a clean way around this issue)

```cs
serviceCollection.Configure<MyConfig>(this.Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig"));
```

> UnhandledException... ...Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'MyConfig'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.

My first thought was to find some way to read the section as a json string (how?) and then deserialize it into an object (e.g. using Newtonsoft or some other json deserialization library). Is there a cleaner approach than this roundabout way?

I also see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65859447/bind-iconfiguration-to-c-sharp-record-type), but this has the problem that it doesn't work with immutable collections.

Comment: `I also see this solution, but this has the problem that it doesn't work with immutable collections` probably you're running into [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77677) which will only be fixed in .NET 8.0. Until then the only way to achieve what you want is via init-only properties as per Qing Guo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core 6 and C# 9 that allows the creation of immutable objects through [Init-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init) properties. As a result, you’ll have the ability to set up your application options so that they’re immutable.

Configure options as immutable like:

```
public record MyConfig
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Names { get; init; }
}
```

In Program.cs(asp.net core 6+) or Startup ConfigureServices:

```
builder.Services.Configure<MyConfig>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MySection"));
```

result:

[image]

Comment: What if the class MyConfig is static as they can't have constructor.